# Change GIS Routing in Anylogic on startup

Tags: anylogic

I want to change the "Routes are:" option of the routing section properties of a GIS Map in Anylogic by code. I need to switch between "Loaded from PBF file" to "Requested from OSM Server" on model startup by code depending on a parameter's value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only programmatically change properties if they are "dynamic".

In this case, it is a "static" property, so must be defined upfront and cannot be changed at runtime.

See [this help article](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FDynamic_Parameters.html&resultof=%22%73%74%61%74%69%63%22%20%22%70%72%6F%70%65%72%74%79%22%20%22%70%72%6F%70%65%72%74%69%22%20) for more info.